# requestLocationUpdates called many time when location changes actually incremented one time

Tags: android

I am sending latitude, longitude and location Name for saving on server.... the problem is when I run my app first time its ok and save above data one time... when I close my app and emulator is running and eclipse also and start my app again then it save above data 2 times..... similarly it incremented by 1 when I close and start again my app... I don't know why it calls `requestLocationUpdates()` many times... without sending to server it works fine.. any idea about this please help me...

sending data to server.. this function is implemented in send.java class

```
public String postData(List<? extends NameValuePair> nameValuePairs, String wurl){

     // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(wurl); 
    try {

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)); 
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(20);
        int current = 0;
        while((current = bis.read()) != -1){
            baf.append((byte)current);
        } 
        /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
        text = new String(baf.toByteArray());

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
    return text;

}
```

onlocationchaned function is in location.java class that implements LocationListener and calling above function inside onlocationchanged

```
public void onLocationChanged(android.location.Location loc) {

    String response;
    latitude = loc.getLatitude();
    longitude = loc.getLongitude();

    // Changing type double to string for sending 
    lati = Double.toString(latitude);
    logi = Double.toString(longitude);

        String Text = "My current location is: " + 
                  " Latitude = " + Location.lati + 
                  " Longitude = "+ Location.logi;
        Toast.makeText(c,  Text , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("lat", "Changed");

        locationName = getAddress(latitude, longitude);

        // Add location related data
        List<BasicNameValuePair> locationNameValuePair = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>(4);
        locationNameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", lati));
        locationNameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", logi));
        locationNameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("locName", locationName));

        response = con.postData(locationNameValuePair, wurl);
        Toast.makeText(c, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.v("IGA", "Address " + locationName);
        Toast.makeText(c, locationName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


 public String getAddress(double lat, double lng) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(c, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        Address obj = addresses.get(0);
        //String add = obj.getAddressLine(0);
        String add = obj.getThoroughfare();
        add = add + ", " + obj.getSubLocality();
        add = add + ", " + obj.getLocality();
        add = add + ", " + obj.getCountryName();

         return add;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(c, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(c, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return "";
}
```

and locationManager in mainavtivity that extends MapActivity

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MapView view = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.themap);
        view.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);


        LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location mylocation = new Location(MainActivity.this);
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mylocation);


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mylocation);
```

should be the following if you want to assure 1000ms have elapsed and the client has moved 5 meters between location updates

```
LocationListener customLocationListener = new CustomLocationListener();
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 5, customLocationListener);
```

Also, in your activity onPause() method call

```
mlocManager .removeUpdates(customLocationListener);
```

You have to implement CustomLocationListener like below:

```
private class CustomeLocationListener implements LocationListener
{
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
    {
        // when location changes, add the record in the database, send to server etc...
        double lat = loc.getLatitude();
        double lon = loc.getLongitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {}
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer @hrehman ... i am already using CustomLocationListener like u told above my that class name is Location... i called that method in onpause() 'mlocManager .removeUpdates(customLocationListener);' but when i change location through eclipse or telnet it gives error 
' threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)

E/AndroidRuntime(1466): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {/com.qau..MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2838)'

Comment: I can't see your LocationListener in the code you posted. Kindly show it to me.

Comment: that was the second block. i just show you onLocationchanged method that is in my own myLocationListener class.. any wayz thanks for your reply i changed in my activity onDestroy() method call 'mlocManager .removeUpdates(customLocationListener);' with one condition and it runs.... again thanks for ur help.....